# From text to dictionary, update keys

Tags: python

I have a text file of this format:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
key3 value4
key1 value5
```

I use a loop (code below) to create a dictionary. I have one problem, that in this text file there are a lot of duplicate keys, but with different values. My loop does not add a new value to an existing key, but completely overwrites it. And as a result, the key remains the value that was last in the file for this key.

I need a dictionary with all keys and all their values.

```
dict = dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    if not line:
        continue
    dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

Comment: How should the dict contain all the values? As lists, or joined to strings?

Comment: @tobias_k how list.

Comment: Well, the dict can not contain duplicate keys, so the keys' values will have to hold more than one element, e.g. in form of a list.

Comment: @tobias_k yep, you are right. I dont need contain duplicate keys, i need only add new values to existing keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lists in your dictionary to store all the values. If there's no list in the dictionary yet, create an empty list first.

```
if not line[0] in dict:
    dict[line[0]] = []
dict[line[0]].append(line[1:])
```

You might also consider

```
dict[line[0]].append(" ".join(line[1:]))
```

to undo the `split()` if you prefer that.

When coding in a good IDE, the IDE will warn you about your use of `dict`:

[image: Warning about shadowing of dict in PyCharm]

What does that mean? It means that you have redefined `dict` and you can never use it again like before:

[image: Error using dict again]

Complete code:

```
result = dict()
for line in ["a a", "b c", "a", "a a2"]:
    line = line.split()
    if not line:
        continue
    if not line[0] in result:
        result[line[0]] = []
    result[line[0]].append(line[1:])
print(result)
```

Comment: It should also be noted that `dict` is a python keyword and is advised not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: @Perplexabot: agreed. PyCharm warns you when doing that

Comment: Thank you! But i have an error in this string : dict[line[0]].append(line[1:]) - "'type' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @StaxDev: for which input data? Please see my full [mcve] code listing

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry, it was my bad, i fixed my mistake. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    if not line:
        continue
    d[line[0]].append(line[1:])
```

Note: Don't use `dict` as a variable name (it is a python keyword).